# custom CIKernel ,Program exceeds GLES uniform limits, when passing parameter to cikernel

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, cifilter

I am trying to build a custom filter which will mess with image's geometry realtime.  I made a very simple warp kernel which maps every single pixel in the current circle into  the central pixel. After exactly 55 iterations the program crashes saying Program exceeds GLES uniform limits. I also noticed that the number of iterations before the crash is always near 55. 
  What are those limits about and how to overcome this problem?
   The problem occurs when the kernel is receiving a parameter, without parameter it works just fine. Any idea?

Kernel code

```
   "kernel vec2 simpleWarp(vec2 center)                      " +
        "{                                                        " +
        "    vec2 p = destCoord();                                " +
        "    float dist = sqrt (dot( p - center, p - center) );   " +
        "    return dist < 50.0 ? center : p;                     " +
        "}                                                        " ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please file a radar bug on this issue.

A work-around would be to insert a pass-though kernel between groups of your warp kernels in order to keep CI from over concatenating:

```
    CIImage* applyPassThrough (CIImage *img)
    {
        static CIKernel *k = nil;
        static NSString * const source = 
              @"kernel vec4 passThrough (sampler s, float v)\n"
               "{ return sample(s, samplerCoord(s)+v); }\n";
        static dispatch_once_t once;
        dispatch_once(&once, ^{
            k = [[CIKernel kernelWithString:source] retain];
        });

        return [k applyWithExtent:img.extent
                      roiCallback:^(int i, CGRect r) { return r; }
                        arguments:@[img, @0.0]];
    }
```